# Increment/Decrement multiple values in an Array at the same time

Tags: java

I have an array of negative and positive integers, such as:

```
int[] nums = [-2, -1, 0, 5, 3]
```

I am trying to zero out each value by either adding or subtracting 1 in the least amount of steps. I am able to take contiguous segments of numbers so long as their sign is the same. For example;

```
Step 0: [-2,-1, 0, 5, 3]
Step 1: [-1, 0, 0, 5, 3]
Step 2: [ 0, 0, 0, 5, 3]
Step 3: [ 0, 0, 0, 4, 2]
Step 4: [ 0, 0, 0, 3, 1]
Step 5: [ 0, 0, 0, 2, 0]
Step 6: [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
Step 7: [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I am lost as to how to grab the segments and increment/decrement them all at the same time. Any hints or suggestions is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post what you have done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling like this is an assignment, so here's just an algorithm, no actual code:

1. loop over all the numbers in the array
2. when you find the first non-zero number, memorize the sign (i.e. `+` or `-`)
3. if you have found a non-zero number and the current number has the same sign, increment/decrement it (depending on what's the sign)
4. if you have found a non-zero number and the current number has a different sign, start over from the beginning
5. when you have reached the end of the array without finding a non-zero number, you are done